# Foundation Modal not opening after clicking

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I'm following Foundation Modal example step by step because I need to open up an slider image gallery inside a modal after clicking over an image, but it doesn't work at all. Reading the docs I understand that is possible to open up a Modal without need of Javascript neither jQuery, just using the data-reveal-id in the launcher and the data-reveal in the div modal you want to open. At least is what I have understood. As it didn't work I've tried with jQuery as well but it doesn't work neither. And I have no errors in console, so I don't suspect where could it be the mistake. I have to say that the modal div is not even hidden despite of I have aria-hidden="true" . Any clue??

This is my first attempt

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/foundation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css">
<script src="assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-img">
  <a href="" data-reveal-id="galleryModal"><img src="assets/images/2.png" alt=""></a>
</div>

<div id="galleryModal" class="reveal-modal full" data-reveal aria-labelledby="galleryModalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  <h2 id="galleryModalTitle">This modal has a gallery</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-1 medium-1 columns">
      <button class="button-slider-gallery previous-button fa fa-chevron-left" id="prev" value="prev"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="large-10 medium-10 columns">
      <div class="slider-gallery">
        <div class="image">
          <img class="width-images" data-lazy="assets/images/paisaje1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <img class="width-images" data-lazy="assets/images/paisaje2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <img class="width-images" data-lazy="assets/images/paisaje3.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 medium-1 columns">
      <button class="button-slider-gallery next-button fa fa-chevron-right" id="next" value="next"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>

//At the end of the page, just before the body closed tag

<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider-gallery').slick({
      lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    });
  });

  $('#prev').click(function(){
    $(".slider-gallery").slick('slickNext');
  });

  $('#next').click(function(){
    $(".slider-gallery").slick('slickPrev');
  });
</script>
```

And this is my second attempt

//Its almost the same but changing the id's of launcher and modal and adding a JQuery function

```
<div class="main-img">
  <a href="" id="modalLauncher"><img src="assets/images/2.png" alt=""></a>
</div>

<div id="galleryModal" class="reveal-modal full" data-reveal aria-labelledby="galleryModalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
  <h2 id="galleryModalTitle">This modal has a gallery</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-1 medium-1 columns">
      <button class="button-slider-gallery previous-button fa fa-chevron-left" id="prev" value="prev"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="large-10 medium-10 columns">
      <div class="slider-gallery">
        <div class="image">
          <img class="width-images" data-lazy="assets/images/paisaje1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <img class="width-images" data-lazy="assets/images/paisaje2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image">
          <img class="width-images" data-lazy="assets/images/paisaje3.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 medium-1 columns">
      <button class="button-slider-gallery next-button fa fa-chevron-right" id="next" value="next"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
</div>

// This also before the body close tag

<script>
  $("#modalLauncher").click(function (e) {
    $('#galleryModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have `<script>$(document).foundation();</script>` after all the other scripts before the closing body tag?

Comment: Yes that was a mistake, but I've tried at the beginning as well and it doesn't work. But I have discovered a very simply way to do it with HTML and CSS wothout using Foundation. And it looks pretty well.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out. FYI `<script>$(document).foundation();</script>` should go after all other scripts and just before the closing body tag. Spent a day once debugging other scripts to only figure out they weren't working because of where I placed the `foundation()` call.